# convert ÿ character to single byte 0xFF python

Tags: python, string, type-conversion, ascii

I'm trying to read a file and send the data to a socket.
But I can't convert a ÿ character to a single byte.

Not if I read a file or use a string and convert it.
I think the problem is the coding of the file but I can't seem to find the correct one.
For this example I will only show the string conversion.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import binascii

s = "ÿ"
b = bytearray(s)
print binascii.hexlify(b)

>>result: c3bf
```

so the ÿ character is stored as 2 bytes.
But I want to convert it to a single bytes that's 0xFF.

thanks in advance

Comment: You probably don't want to do that at all. You probably you confused the UTF16 representation (U+00FF, ie 0x00,0xFF) for a single byte. I don't thing there's any ASCII codepage where the *last* character is printable. If you check the [codepage charts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page#DOS_code_pages) you'll see that in most cases 0xFF is a `non-breaking space`. *Why* do you want to use `0xFF` ?

Comment: *"But I can't convert a ÿ character to a single byte."* - Why would you want to do that?

Comment: hi, I (we) are making a printer but the windows driver is not finished yet. 
I was trying to test the embedded application.

I found that my file wasn't stored correctly so I can do it with a file right now. But still can't with a const string.

As example this work to get the correct value:

`code`
with open('test.prn', "rb") as f:
    byte = f.read(1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

> s.decode("utf-8")

Output:

[image: Reults]

Comment: thanks for your reply.
this results in "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xff' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)"

Comment: I used python 2.7.14, I attached output image

Comment: hi, I don't know but I tried it again and it work thanks